# Cygwin installs package always from cache

Tags: cygwin

I've tried to update the postgresql-client package from 10.2 up to 11.5
Because there's no really update option, I removed the package and reinstall via

```
apt-get install postgresql-client
```

But Cygwin gets the old 10.2 cached version. How can I remove the cached file to force apt-get to be download and install  the most current one?

Comment: Have you tried using the officially supported setup.exe from the official cygwin web site?

Comment: No, the Cygwin installation I'm using came from mobaxterm. I will give it a try.